# Does the index count towards the max Firestore storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), that max size of a document is 1 Mib. I know that the index also count. Are the indexes and other storage overhead contained in this 1 Mib? Or the max of 1,048,576 bytes is only used for fields and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max document size is just for the document itself.  It doesn't count any indexes that are created to help queries for all of the documents in the collection.